# Google Bar Chart - How to get 2 different bars for each entry with JSON

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, charts

I want to get such a bar chart with 2 different bars:
[Google bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJOz3.jpg)

But i do not know, how to do this with JSON. I want to have a red and a blue bar for each x-axis entry.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$query = "SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN name_Gleitzeitrahmen = 'Ja' THEN 1 END) as Ja,COUNT(CASE WHEN name_Gleitzeitrahmen = 'Nein' THEN 1 END)as Nein,quarter(datum) as quartal FROM dashboard GROUP BY quartal";
$exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);


$rows = array();
//flag is not needed
$flag = true;
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(

// Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles
percentage and string will be used for column title
array('label' => 'quartal', 'type' => 'string'),
array('label' => 'Ja', 'type' => 'number'),
array('label' => 'Nein', 'type' => 'number')
);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exec)) {
$temp = array();
// the following line will be used to slice the Pie chart
$temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['quartal']); 

// Values of each slice
$temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Ja'] ); 
$temp[] = array('s' => (int) $r['Nein']); 
$rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

 $table['rows'] = $rows;
 $jsonTable = json_encode($table);

 ?>
```

The actual chart looks like this:  [Actual chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S69wY.jpg)

Format must be like this:

```
 function drawStuff() {
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Galaxy', 'Distance', 'Brightness'],
      ['Canis Major Dwarf', 8000, 23.3],
      ['Sagittarius Dwarf', 24000, 4.5],
      ['Ursa Major II Dwarf', 30000, 14.3],
      ['Lg. Magellanic Cloud', 50000, 0.9],
      ['Bootes I', 60000, 13.1]
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer now!

I tried several combinations and finally found the correct one.

Here it is:

```
$rows = array();
//flag is not needed
$flag = true;
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(

// Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles
// Note that one column is in "string" format and another one is in "number" format as pie chart only required "numbers" for calculating percentage and string will be used for column title
array('label' => 'Quartal', 'type' => 'string'),
array('label' => 'Anzahl Ja', 'type' => 'number'),
array('label' => 'Anzahl Nein', 'type' => 'number')
);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exec)) {
$temp = array();
// the following line will be used to slice the Pie chart
$temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['quartal']); 

// Values of each slice
$temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Ja'] ); 
$temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Nein'] );
$rows[] = array('c' => $temp);

}
```